# SecureString claims it is defined in mscorlib, but it could not be found in visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: adal

Getting below error when I run the below code in visual studio 2015 RC, but same piece of code runs perfectly in visual studio 2013.

**Reference to type 'SecureString' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found**

```
public static AuthenticationResult GetAccessToken(string strAuthority, string strClientId, string strAppKey, string strResourceID)
    {
        AuthenticationResult token = null;
        ClientCredential clientCredential = null;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(strAuthority);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(strClientId, strAppKey);
        int retryCount = 0;
        bool retry = false;
        do
        {
            retry = false;
            try
            {
                token = authContext.AcquireToken(strResourceID, clientCredential);
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
                {
                    retry = true;
                    retryCount++;
                }
            }
        } while ((retry == true) && (retryCount < 3));
        return token;
    }
```